# Pillow and JPEG2000: decoder jpeg2k not available

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg2000

I'm trying to set up Flask-IIIF to work with `jp2`-files, or JPEG2000. Right out of the box I get an error from the Pillow library: `IOError: decoder jpeg2k not available`

I've tried googling it, and one StackOverflow post told me to make sure `libjpeg-dev` and `libjpeg8-dev` are installed and up to date, but they were already installed. After making sure they were there, I did try to reinstall pillow without cache: `pip install --no-cache-dir -I pillow`

The environment is Docker, based on a **15.10 Ubuntu** image. Python version is **2.7.10**. Pillow version from pip freeze is **4.1.1**

edit: I also tried the other suggestion of [Python Image Library fails with message "decoder JPEG not available" - PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915296/python-image-library-fails-with-message-decoder-jpeg-not-available-pil):

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pillow needs the OpenJPEG library to decode JPEG2000 files. libjpeg only deals with regular JPEGs.

See the note in the Pillow docs at the end of this section: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg-2000

Answer (score 7):

### for linux

```sh
sudo yum install -y libjpeg-devel
sudo pip uninstall pillow
sudo pip install pillow
```

#### for windows

```py
# download
import imageio
imageio.plugins.freeimage.download()
```

```py
# install
pip uninstall pillow
pip install pillow
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows users:
After you installed OpenJPEG and added its bin folder to PATH, you need to re-build the pillow library. Using Conda I didn't find a solution to do that so I ended up using the windows installer from PyPi as [suggested in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184995/how-do-i-install-openjpeg-on-windows-and-use-it-with-pillow). The installer found my Anaconda installation and it seems it simply overwrote the pillow library there.