# How to add dicom tags for a series of dicom images?

Tags: python-3.x, pydicom

I want to add Dicom tags to a series of Dicom images and want to save that modified batch.

I have written a simple python script using pydicom which can edit and add dicom tags in a single Dicom image, but i want to do same procedure for complete image set (say 20 or 30 images).
can anybody suggest me a way to do such task using pydicom or python?

Comment: have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312690/2878353  .

Comment: import pydicom
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files
from pydicom.dataset import Dataset, FileDataset
from pydicom.filereader import dcmread

ds = dcmread("IMAGE.dcm")

ds.add_new(0x00180020, 'CS', 'GR')
ds.add_new(0x00180021, 'CS', 'SP\OSP')

ds.save_as("MR.dcm") #This adds two dicom tags in my image and save it as new MR Image, but i want to make this change to a list of images

Answer (score 1):

Just collect your filenames in a list and process each filename (read the file, edit contents, save as new or maybe use the same name).
Have a look at the `os` module from python. For instance, `os.listdir('path')` returns a list of filenames found in the given path. If that path points to a directory that contains only dicom images you now have a list of dicom filenames. Next use `os.path.join('path', filename)` to get an absolute path that you can use as input for reading a dicom file with pydicom.
Also you might want to use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a list of dicom image file paths in an array named `dicom_paths`. Then:

```
import pydicom
dicom_paths = [ list of image paths here ]
dicom_data = [pydicom.read_file(s) for s in dicom_paths]
for dicom_data_item in dicom_data:
    #do what you want here
```

Hope it helps