# NotImplementedError: this transfer syntax JPEG 2000 Image Compression, can not be read because Pillow lacks the jpeg 2000 decoder plugin

Tags: python, pydicom, jpeg2000

I am running codes to visualizing and analyzing DICOM images in Python. The time I run the code to extract DICOM pixels for each slice location and display a single slice, I am getting the following error: `NotImplementedError: this transfer syntax JPEG 2000 Image Compression, can not be read because Pillow lacks the jpeg 2000 decoder plugin`
Here is a link to a tutorial that I am following: [Link to the tutorial](https://medium.com/@hengloose/a-comprehensive-starter-guide-to-visualizing-and-analyzing-dicom-images-in-python-7a8430fcb7ed)

My code as below:

```
# set path and load files 
path = 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\DICOM\\series-00000\\'
patient_dicom = load_scan(path)
patient_pixels = get_pixels_hu(patient_dicom)
#sanity check
plt.imshow(patient_pixels[326], cmap=plt.cm.bone)
```

And the error is:

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c775fc5d5328> in <module>
      2 path = 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\DICOM\\series-00000\\'
      3 patient_dicom = load_scan(path)
----> 4 patient_pixels = get_pixels_hu(patient_dicom)
      5 #sanity check
      6 plt.imshow(patient_pixels[326], cmap=plt.cm.bone)

<ipython-input-28-1f0488edc728> in get_pixels_hu(scans)
      1 def get_pixels_hu(scans):
----> 2     image = np.stack([s.pixel_array for s in scans])
      3     image = image.astype(np.int16)
      4     # Set outside-of-scan pixels to 0
      5     # The intercept is usually -1024, so air is approximately 0

<ipython-input-28-1f0488edc728> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 def get_pixels_hu(scans):
----> 2     image = np.stack([s.pixel_array for s in scans])
      3     image = image.astype(np.int16)
      4     # Set outside-of-scan pixels to 0
      5     # The intercept is usually -1024, so air is approximately 0

~\Anaconda3\64X-Install\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in pixel_array(self)
   1613             :class:`numpy.ndarray`.
   1614         """
-> 1615         self.convert_pixel_data()
   1616         return self._pixel_array
   1617 

~\Anaconda3\64X-Install\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in convert_pixel_data(self, handler_name)
   1322             self._convert_pixel_data_using_handler(handler_name)
   1323         else:
-> 1324             self._convert_pixel_data_without_handler()
   1325 
   1326     def _convert_pixel_data_using_handler(self, name):

~\Anaconda3\64X-Install\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in _convert_pixel_data_without_handler(self)
   1432             .format(", ".join([str(hh) for hh in available_handlers]))
   1433         )
-> 1434         raise last_exception
   1435 
   1436     def _do_pixel_data_conversion(self, handler):

~\Anaconda3\64X-Install\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in _convert_pixel_data_without_handler(self)
   1412         for handler in available_handlers:
   1413             try:
-> 1414                 self._do_pixel_data_conversion(handler)
   1415                 return
   1416             except Exception as exc:

~\Anaconda3\64X-Install\lib\site-packages\pydicom\dataset.py in _do_pixel_data_conversion(self, handler)
   1439         # Use the handler to get a 1D numpy array of the pixel data
   1440         # Will raise an exception if no pixel data element
-> 1441         arr = handler.get_pixeldata(self)
   1442         self._pixel_array = reshape_pixel_array(self, arr)
   1443 

~\Anaconda3\64X-Install\lib\site-packages\pydicom\pixel_data_handlers\pillow_handler.py in get_pixeldata(ds)
    132                "Pillow lacks the jpeg 2000 decoder plugin"
    133                .format(transfer_syntax.name))
--> 134         raise NotImplementedError(msg)
    135 
    136     if transfer_syntax == pydicom.uid.JPEGExtended and ds.BitsAllocated != 8:

NotImplementedError: this transfer syntax JPEG 2000 Image Compression, can not be read because Pillow lacks the jpeg 2000 decoder plugin
```

I installed all the recommended pakages including Pillow and my Python version is 3.7.
I installed openJPEG via anaconda prompt by running the following command `conda install -c conda-forge openjpeg` and is still giving me the same error.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pillow and JPEG2000: decoder jpeg2k not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782612/pillow-and-jpeg2000-decoder-jpeg2k-not-available)

Comment: Did you reinstall pillow after installing openjpeg?

Comment: It seems that some libs and packages doesn't work with python 3.7 and above. I had to remove Anaconda from my computer completely and installed it again. Then downgraded to python 3.6.10 since the default for Jubyter Notebook is 3.7 through Anaconda Prompt. Then I installed the required libs and packages, however, it did not work with Jubyter Notebook instead worked perfectly with JubyterLab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some libs and packages doesn't work with python 3.7 and above. I had to remove Anaconda from my computer completely and installed it again. Then downgraded to python 3.6.10 since the default for Jubyter Notebook is 3.7 through Anaconda Prompt. Then I installed the required libs and packages, however, it did not work with Jubyter Notebook instead worked perfectly with JubyterLab.